# Is possible to secure a Rails API using session cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an issue. I have two Rails website, site A and site B.
Site A is a news website that has device as auth system and use Disqus with Single Sign On to comment contents.

Site B is another news website that doesn't have any user auth system and use Disqus to comment contents but without single sign on.

I want to permit to users of the site A to SSO on Disqus on site B.
Disqus SSO use this script

```
def get_disqus_sso(user)
    # create a JSON packet of our data attributes
    data =  {
      'id' => user['id'],
      'username' => user['username'],
      'email' => user['email']
      #'avatar' => user['avatar'],
      #'url' => user['url']
    }.to_json

    # encode the data to base64
    message  = Base64.encode64(data).gsub("\n", "")
    # generate a timestamp for signing the message
    timestamp = Time.now.to_i
    # generate our hmac signature
    sig = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha1', DISQUS_SECRET_KEY, '%s %s' % [message, timestamp])

    # return a script tag to insert the sso message
    return "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var disqus_config = function() {
            this.page.remote_auth_s3 = \"#{message} #{sig} #{timestamp}\";
            this.page.api_key = \"#{DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY}\";
        }
    </script>"
end
```

Of course on site B I don't have any user, buy I think to create a private API on site A that return to a logged user `"#{message} #{sig} #{timestamp}\"`

Is possible to create an API that return something using as auth method the session cookie created by Devise after a successful auth?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's possible with using jwt. the flow goes as follows.
(tested only with subdomains)

`user uses siteA(stores generated jwt token in a cookie) --> siteB uses the jwt token in cookie --> sends token to siteA for user data --> gets user data.`

jwt authentication [example](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/)

**note**: only works for subdomains and don't forget to sign the cookie to prevent tampering.